# How to retrieve the records from more than one table which has one to many relationship?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How to retrieve the records from more than one table which has one to many relationship.

```
Categories[table]
CategoryId
CategoryName

Products[table]
ProductId
CategoryId
ProductName
Description
```

Entites

```
 Category[Entity]
 CategoryId
 CategoryName
 List<Product>

Product[Entity]
ProductId
ProductName
Description
```

So if i give categoryId, i should get the category details with list of products associated with the category.

How to do this in linq to sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linq to sql you get a reference property generated in each of your entities. This said if you do this:

```
Category cat = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.CategoryId == 1); //Where one is the //id of a random category
foreach(Product prd in cat.Products)
{
//do some logic here
}
```

you will get all the products.

Answer (score 1):

See [Include for LINQ to SQL](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/05/21/include-for-linq-to-sql-and-maybe-other-providers)